# Does Visual Studio 2013 Express require space on the system drive?

Tags: hard-drive, installation, disk-space, requirements, visual-studio-2013

Does Visual Studio 2013 Express require space on the system drive? I have only ~5GB free on C:/. I ask because I remember that VS2012 takes lots of space on system drive even if you choose to install to another drive. Hardware requirements([source](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx)):

- 1.6 GHz or faster processor
- 1 GB of RAM (1.5 GB if running on a virtual machine)
- **4 GB of available hard disk space**
- 5400 RPM hard drive
- DirectX 9-capable video card running at 1024 x 768 or higher display resolution

Comment: Off topic, but surely you should be thinking about addressing the issue of having such little memory left on the C?

Comment: The requirements seem to be crystal clear.  VS2013 Express uses between 4GB and 5GB of storage depending on the specific installation you download and install.

Comment: Requirements also say 10GB for VS2012 but do not mention space on system drive.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's about where files will be installed - this may alter with newer releases of the software and as such, the answer may not be relevant in the near future. This may mean, if you did an update, it may then also decide to add/install more files at certain sections of your machine

Comment: @Daniel - Question is specifically about VS2013 Express not VS2012

Comment: Yes, but I want to show how "crystal clear" those requirements are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes.  Many of the components that any version of VS installs, must install on the system drive.  VS2013 is no different than previous versions in this regard.  Exact space required will vary widely based on installation components chosen and what you may have already installed on your system.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio requires much more space because of the different kind of stuff installed alongside with it.

Also, there may be a possibility that even if you install it on another drive, most of the files will be copied to the `C: (Windows Directory)` like it happens with `Solidworks 64 bit 2013`

Source :-
Installed `VS Ultimate` and it is taking `~14.86GB on C drive`.